# Setting CSS with javascript is not behaving smoothly

Tags: jquery, css, animation, heroku

Im creating a personal resume site and hosting it with heroku right now. Im using Jquery and my issue is that when Im developing locally my window.ready function which sets some css is very smooth, however when I deploy it it becomes very glitchy adn slow. Ive tried adding the transform: translateZ(0); to enhance it and ive tried minifying my javascript. The code is below if anyone knows whats making it so laggy Id appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
  $(window).ready(() => {
  $(window).width() > 768 &&
    ((startPos = parseInt(
      $(".one")
        .css("top")
        .slice(0, 4)
    )),
    $(".name-container").css({ "transition-duration": "2s", opacity: "1" }),
    $(".home-mid-text").css({ "transition-duration": "2s", opacity: "1" }),
    $("#nav").css({ "transition-duration": "2s", "margin-left": "135px" }),
    $(".container").css({
      "transition-duration": "2s",
      padding: "50px 140px"
    }));
}),
  $("#date-2019").hover(
    () => {
      $("#date-2019").css({
        "transition-duration": "1.2s",
        transform: "rotate(0)"
      });
    },
    () => {
      $("#date-2019").css({ transform: "rotate(90deg)" });
    }
  );
```

Heres a link to the page 
http://kaiferrall.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Why don’t you use CSS? Why set it by script? And where do you use startPos variable?

Comment: @IgorMelekhov the startPost variable isn’t used I got rid of it that was just from before. And I’m setting the css with JavaScript because I want it to run when the page loads so the elements move into view.

Comment: I would set transition duration in css before page load, then add class .loaded for every element with needed properties and in jQuery just add this class.

Comment: @IgorMelekhov great thanks so much I think that solved it. I guess it’s just a more efficient method.

Comment: I’m glad this helped.